# generating a random number everytime in a loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to simulate blobs reproducing and dying and every blob has a reproduction- and death chance. Every time in a loop it is supposed to generate a random rumber to see if the death and birth rate is bigger than the random number, if yes, create or delete a blob. every blob is stored in a list blobs.

THe problem is that it seems to generate 1 number for all blobs so eiter no one dies or everyone dies at once, but i want different randoms for each blob. For example reproduction -and deathchance are 0.5.

```
for blob in blobs:
        if blob.reproduce_chance > random.uniform(0,1):
            blobs.append(blob)
        if blob.death_chance > random.uniform(0,1):
            blobs.pop(blobs.index(blob))
```

Comment: "THe problem is that it seems to generate 1 number for all blobs" What makes you say that? Did you add debug output to check that assumption?

Comment: I printed the length of the blob list each time so I can see how many blobs are in there and they always add up to a number and then drop to 0 in 1 go, then went up again. I tested it with a 0.05 death chance

Comment: You are changing `blobs` while iterating over it. That's generally considered a bad idea, and may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Well, I ran this snippet, and as expected, I can not reproduce the issue. I'll put it in the answer.

Comment: Additionally: `blobs.append(blob)` will not add a *new* blob but a *copy* of an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import random

variation = 0

for blob in range(10):
        if 0.5 > random.uniform(0,1):
            print("New born at blob", blob)
            variation += 1
        if 0.5 > random.uniform(0,1):
            print("Death at blob", blob)
            variation -= 1
print("Blob count change:", variation)
```

Output:

```
Death at blob 1
New born at blob 2
Death at blob 2
New born at blob 4
Death at blob 4
New born at blob 5
Death at blob 5
New born at blob 6
Death at blob 6
New born at blob 7
New born at blob 8
Blob count change: 1
```

So the problem is **not** with the random number generator.
As said in the comments, it may be due to changing a list while iterating over it.